# How can i prevent form submission when a file is being removed or uploaded?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, files

I have a node form for my custom content type. There is file field in that content type. And i want to prevent form submission when a file is being removed and uploaded. 
Note: File removed and uploaded via ajax.
any help please

Comment: Please aware that if the form cannot be submitted successfully, the file won't be successfully removed or uploaded.

Comment: Maybe this is a case of making the field more obvious to the user that the file is still uploading to deter them from clicking submit? Can you show file progress with APC? If not, https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup is a great module for showing a progress bar.

Comment: i want to restrict user to not submit form